# I am getting error in scraping scroll down page

Tags: selenium, web-scraping

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException 
import time
import sys
import pandas as pd
import mysql.connector


mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="danish-khan",
  password="12345",
  db='reseachgate_profiles'
)

cur = mydb.cursor()


#create table
cur.execute("""DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Data2""")

cur.execute(''' CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Data2
               (Id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
                Name varchar(255),
                Institution VARCHAR(255),
                Department varchar(255),
                Citations INTEGER,
                Recommendation INTEGER, 
                Total_Reads INTEGER, 
                Total_research_interest DECIMAL(7,1), 
                Research_items INTEGER,
                Projects INTEGER, 
                Questions  INTEGER,
                Answers INTEGER, 
                Scores  DECIMAL(7,1),
                Followers INTEGER,
                Followings INTEGER
               )''')



login_url = 'https://www.researchgate.net/login'
base_url = "https://www.researchgate.net/institution/COMSATS-University-Islamabad/department/Department-of-Computer-Science/members"
chrome_driver_path = '/home/danish-khan/scrapers/researchgate/chromedriver'

chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(
  executable_path=chrome_driver_path, options=chrome_options
)

# default login credential and search query
username = 'your username'
password = 'your password'

results = []
total_profiles = []

with webdriver as driver:
    # Set timeout time 
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

    # retrive url in headless browser
    driver.get(login_url)
    
    driver.find_element_by_id("input-login").send_keys(username)
    driver.find_element_by_id("input-password").send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_class_name("nova-c-button__label").find_element(By.XPATH, "./..").click()
    time.sleep(2)

    driver.get(base_url)

    time.sleep(3)
    #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    #names = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.display-name')
    #name = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//ul[@class="list people-list-m"]/li//a[@class="display-name"]')
    last_height = driver.execute_script('return document.body.scrollHeight')
    print('height:',last_height)
    time.sleep(5)
   
    while True:
       # Scroll down to bottom
      driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    
      time.sleep(2)
      
      #driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(1, 5000);")
      new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
      print('new height:' +str(new_height))
      if new_height == last_height:
          break
      last_height = new_height    
    total_profiles.append(last_height)
    links = '//ul[@class="list people-list-m"]/li//a[@class="display-name"]'
    name = WebDriverWait(driver, 5).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, links))
              )
    print(len(name))
    lenname = len(name)
    total_profiles = total_profiles[0]
    print('total  profiles:', total_profiles)
    #selector = '.display-name'
    selector = '//ul[@class="list people-list-m"]/li//a[@class="display-name"]'
   
    for i in range(0,lenname-1):
            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
        
            time.sleep(5)
            links = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
            EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, selector))
              )
                     
            links[i].click()

            details = {
                'Name' : driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.nova-e-text--size-xl.nova-e-text--color-grey-900').text,
                'Institution' : '',
                'Department' : driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.nova-v-institution-item__info-section-list-item .nova-e-link--theme-bare').text,
                'Citations' : '',
                'Recommendation' : '',
                'Total_Reads' : '',
                'Total_research_interest' : '',
                'Research_items' : '',
                'Projects' : '',
                'Questions' : '',
                'Answers' : '',
                'Scores' : '',
                'Followings' : '',
                'Followers' : ''
        
             }
    
    
            try:
              Institution = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.nova-v-institution-item__title .nova-e-link--theme-bare').text
            except:
              Institution = 'N/A'
            
            try:   
              Citations = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--m:nth-child(2) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text
              Citations = int(Citations.replace(",", ""))
            except:
              Citations = 0 
                 
            try:     
              Recommendation =   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--m:nth-child(3) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text
              Recommendation = int(Recommendation.replace(' ', ''))
            except:
              Recommendation = 0 
            
            try:  
              Total_Reads = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--m:nth-child(4) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text                      
              Total_Reads = int(Total_Reads.replace(",", ""))
            except:
              Total_Reads = 0 
            
            try:
              Total_research_interest =   driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--m:nth-child(1) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text           
              Total_research_interest = float(Total_research_interest)
            except:
              Total_research_interest = 0.0
            
            try:
              Research_items = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--xs:nth-child(1) .nova-e-text--color-inherit').text
              Research_items = int(Research_items)
            except:
              Research_items = 0
            
            try:
              Projects = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--xs:nth-child(2) .nova-e-text--color-inherit').text
              Projects = int(Projects)
            except:
              Projects = 0

            try:   
              Questions = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--xs:nth-child(3) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text
              Questions = int(Questions)
            except:
              Questions = 0
            
            try:
              Answers = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.application-box-layout__item--xs:nth-child(4) .nova-e-text--size-xl').text
              Answers = int(Answers)
            except:
              Answers = 0
            
            
            try:
                Scores = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.profile-header-details-meta-items .nova-e-list__item:nth-child(1)').text
                
                Scores = float(Scores)
            except: 
                Scores = 0
            
            try:                             
              Followings = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath = "//*[contains(text(), 'Following')]").text.strip('Following').strip('( )')
              
              Followings = int(Followings)
            except:
              Followings = 0
            
            try:                             
              Followers = driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath = "//*[contains(text(), 'Followers')]").text.strip('Followers').strip('( )')

              Followers = int(Followers)
            except:
              Followers = 0  
            
            
            
            details['Institution'] = Institution 
            details['Citations'] =  Citations
            details['Recommendation'] =  Recommendation
            details['Total_Reads'] = Total_Reads 
            details['Total_research_interest'] = Total_research_interest 
            details['Research_items'] =  Research_items
            details['Projects'] = Projects 
            details['Questions'] = Questions 
            details['Answers'] =  Answers 
            details['Scores'] =  Scores
            details['Followings'] = Followings
            details['Followers'] = Followers
             
            results.append(details)
            driver.back()

            time.sleep(5)
            

profile_details = pd.DataFrame(results)
print(profile_details)

for row in profile_details.itertuples():
            
    cur.execute('''INSERT INTO Data2
                (Name,
                Institution,
                Department,
                Citations,
                Recommendation,
                Total_Reads,
                Total_research_interest,
                Research_items , Projects,
                Questions,
                Answers,
                Scores,
                Followers, 
                Followings)
                VALUES
                ("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s", "%s" )''',
                (row.Name,
                row.Institution,
                row.Department,
                row.Citations,
                row.Recommendation,
                row.Total_Reads,
                row.Total_research_interest,
                row.Research_items,
                row.Projects,
                row.Questions,
                row.Answers,
                row.Scores,
                row.Followers,
                row.Followings ) )
                  
            
mydb.commit()
        
print('complete.')
  

mydb.close()
time.sleep(5)

driver.close()
```

I am scraping **researchgate.com** website user profile institution wise and in institution department wise and if the department members are less in number then it is scraped and if the department members are greater in number then is not scraping and give me the error.

```
 resgt3.py
height: 1907
new height:2622
new height:3342
new height:4062
new height:4792
new height:5517
new height:6247
new height:6967
new height:7692
new height:8412
new height:9127
new height:9857
new height:10577
new height:11307
new height:12022
new height:12752
new height:13477
new height:14217
new height:14937
new height:15647
new height:16367
new height:17092
new height:17817
new height:18547
new height:19267
new height:20002
new height:20727
new height:21442
new height:22167
new height:22887
new height:23622
new height:24347
new height:25072
new height:25797
new height:26517
new height:27247
new height:27967
new height:28692
new height:29417
new height:30142
new height:30862
new height:31582
new height:32312
new height:33032
new height:33747
new height:34457
new height:35187
new height:35902
new height:36632
new height:37357
new height:38082
new height:38812
new height:39542
new height:40267
new height:40997
new height:41722
new height:42447
new height:43182
new height:43912
new height:44637
new height:45357
new height:46077
new height:46802
new height:47527
new height:48252
new height:48982
new height:49712
new height:50437
new height:51157
new height:51877
new height:52607
new height:53337
new height:54062
new height:54787
new height:55507
new height:56247
new height:56972
new height:57697
new height:58417
new height:59137
new height:59862
new height:60587
new height:61312
new height:62027
new height:62757
new height:63487
new height:64197
new height:64917
new height:65647
new height:66372
new height:67092
new height:67822
new height:68557
new height:69282
new height:70007
new height:70732
new height:71457
new height:72187
new height:72907
new height:73632
new height:74372
new height:75087
new height:75807
new height:76532
new height:77257
new height:77987
new height:78717
new height:79427
new height:80152
new height:80867
new height:81587
new height:82322
new height:83037
new height:83762
new height:84487
new height:85202
new height:85927
new height:86642
new height:87367
new height:88092
new height:88812
new height:89522
new height:90257
new height:90982
new height:91717
new height:92235
new height:92235
1268
total  profiles: 92235
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "resgt3.py", line 121, in <module>
    links[i].click()
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I don't think why this happens This website is just like Linkedin but I want to know the reason why this error is got and any solution for this.

Comment: This happen because the variable [i] is bigger than the size of your links list web element. Re-check [links = '//ul[@class="list people-list-m"]/li//a[@class="display-name"]']. I see it duplicate two time in your code.

Comment: Thats not the answers of my question

Comment: I mean how i can scraped all the profiles which are larger in number in scroll down page